# CSS transition background-image jump hover in Safari

Tags: css, safari, transition

I have an issue with a transition effect in Safari and could use some help. My CSS hover swaps background images, as it should, but the hover image 'jumps' from its position, up and to the left (which I don't want to happen). Thanks.

Structure:

```css
.sidebar .widget {
 height: 276px;
 width: 326px;
 background:url('/wp-content/themes/a-theme/svg/polygon-image.svg') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: 100%;
}

.sidebar .widget:hover {
 background:url('/wp-content/themes/a-theme/svg/polygon-image-hover.svg') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: 100%;
 transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <aside id="black-studio-tinymce-18" class="widget widget_black_studio_tinymce">
  <div class="textwidget">
   <h3 style="text-align: center;">Sample Text<br></h3>
  </div>
 </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I see your images?

Answer (score 0):

avoid browsers bugs and clean:

```
.sidebar .widget {
    height: 276px;
    width: 326px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image:url(/wp-content/themes/a-theme/svg/polygon-image.svg);
    background-size: 100%;
    transition:background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar .widget:hover {
    background-image:url(/wp-content/themes/a-theme/svg/polygon-image-hover.svg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your help, I modified my CSS to get exactly what I needed. I had a background image of a polygon shape and a graphic in the middle of it. I kept the graphic and used a CSS polygon for the shape, instead, and now my hover effect works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

See my CSS below and thanks again for the replies.

```css
sidebar .widget {
 background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/image.png') no-repeat center center;
 background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.85);
 background-size: 70%;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%);
 clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%);
 height: 276px;
 width: 326px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .widget:hover {
 background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/image.png') no-repeat center center;
 background-color: rgba(108, 218, 244, 0.8);
 background-size: 80%;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%);
 clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%);
 height: 276px;
 width: 326px;
 transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```